# Append element (rect) with variable width after each x-axis coordinate position from previous element

Tags: d3.js

I want to append each rect element exactly after previous element x-axis coordinate. My current code is:

```
var data = [50,100,150]

var svg = d3.select("#bar_chart")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", "1000")
    .attr("height", "500")

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return (d * i) })
        .attr("y", "300")
        .attr("width", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("height", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .each(function(d, i) {console.log(i.x)})
```

Which gives the following:
[Code with x-axis position set to return (d * i)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOGK6.jpg)

What I would like: 
[Code with x-axis from each element start immediately after the previous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRvOh.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the widths prior to your current width.

https://jsfiddle.net/8dv1y74e/

```
var data = [50,100,150]

var svg = d3.select("#bar_chart")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", "1000")
    .attr("height", "500")

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", getPreviousWidths)
        .attr("y", "300")
        .attr("width", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("height", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .each(function(d, i) {console.log(i.x)})

function getPreviousWidths(d,i){
    return data.slice(0,i).reduce((memo,num)=>num+memo,0)
}
```

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for your answer. I tried apply these methods slice <https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control> and reduce <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example> before, but I could't. I'm studying JavaScript and your answer help-me clarify some things.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to the other answer, you can use a variable to keep track of the x coordinate for the most recent rectangle, adding to it each time you append a rectangle:

```js
var data = [50,100,150];

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", "500")
    .attr("height", "500");

var positionX = 0; // where we are on the x axis, first element should be at 0 pixels.

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { 
                  var x = positionX;  // The x value for this rectangle
                  positionX = d + x;  // The x value for the next rectangle
                  return x;           // Return the x value for this rectangle.
         })
        .attr("y", "10")
        .attr("width", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("height", function(d, i){ return d})
        .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, thanks for your answer. I'm a newbie in JavaScript and d3js, and your answer is very clear: your code are clearly commented. I accepted the answer from Eric because came before yours, and I used first in implementation, nevertheless, I up-vote your answer because is right, synthetic and elegant too.